# Regarding creating flavors in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm making a project in which I've added two flavors dev and prod and I need to make two firebase projects for the same as I want to store different values in the database for different environments.I have made two separate firebase projects for Dev and Prod where I have two google-services.json and two google-info.plist files. To manage them I've added them in two separate folders in app/src named release and development. Whenever I try to run the flavors, it's showing an error. The error is this:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'flutter_flavors\android\app\build.gradle' line: 58
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not find method flavorDimensions() for arguments [app] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDevDebug'...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Share your `flutter_flavors\android\app\build.gradle` please. Make sure to remove any sensitive/secret information.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and solved it by moving the flavor snippets to be a child of the android section, as below. Previously I had it after app{} and had the same error as above.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    signingConfigs {
       ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors{
        local {
            dimension "app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Removed"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            applicationId "xxxx"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Removed"
            applicationId "xxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The doc's did not make this clear. For non android developers using Flutter like myself, it would have been great if the documentation was more explicit at this step.